# connect to a DB inside awk script

Tags: sql, unix, shell, sed, awk

In a shell script we can connect to a Database using sqlplus on unix.
can i perform the same thing inside an awk script?
i need to access the output of a select query inside an awk script.is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do the query and feed the output of it into awk:

```
sqlplus 'select onething from another' | awk '{ weave awk magic here }'
```

Just like any other command:

```
pax> ls -alF | awk '{print $9}'
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
    my_p0rn_dir/
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use some sort of command line client for your SQL database (if available) and pipe the output to `awk`.

E.g. with `sqlite` (I don't know what client SQL*Plus has):

```
echo "select * from foo;" | sqlite3 file.db | awk ...
```

`awk` can't do it. This is UNIX tools philosophy, instead of having few tools that do many tasks, you use many little tools that do one task and connect them together.